# Trying to identify this old font

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify the font below, It was something I made like 25 years ago, but I neither have the font nor remember what the font was that was used.

The G is quite unique. I tried "What the font" but while it came up with fonts, none of them were right.

Was hoping someone would be able to identify it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, sorry, but Ad Lib is a font in this genre (sans-serif but with eccentric, paper-cut-out style). Perhaps look at fonts inspired by it.